# Embedding CefSharp Browser v107.1.120 in C# WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, cefsharp

I used CefSharp embedded browser in desktop app WinForms before (v106.0.260) and all worked well.
With the latest 107.1.120 I do have a problem - it throws exception at the line:

```
if (Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: false, browserProcessHandle: null) == false)
```

The exception is: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp, Version=107.1.120.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I installed CefSharp.Common and CefSharp.WinForms, both from NuGet, and have both of them showing in References (VS2022).

More info: I build the project as AnyCPU, and it builds fine. However, the build creates 2 directories under the Debug folder: x64, x86, and some of the files are located in the under Debug (CefSharp.dll, CefSharp.WiForms.dll, CefSharp.Common.dll) and the rest are under x64 and x86 subfolders). I wonder whether the app cannot find one of the DLLs in the x64/x86 subfolder...and if yes, how to I tell the project where to look for them...
What else can it be?

Searching for the solution, I copied files from x64 subfolder to Debug folder, but then when I run I get exception System.IO.FileNotFoundException even before the above line, when I try to execute the 2nd line below:

```
CefRuntime.SubscribeAnyCpuAssemblyResolver();
Cef.EnableHighDPISupport();
.........
if (Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: false, browserProcessHandle: null) == false)
```

Comment: Have you deleted your bin/obj directories? or even better performed a clean checkout from source control?

Comment: Yes, I tried it all. Eventually I put together a simple WinForms app and was able to run it without initialization problem. However, I cannot catch any WebSocket packets. I will post my code. Sam code worked before in another completely different project.

Comment: How many projects are in your solution? Are there multiple referencing CefSharp? Did you upgrade them all? The runtime is trying to load CefSharp.dll and cannot find the correct version, check which version is in your bin folder. Not sure how websockets are related, keep the issue confined to a single problem please.

Comment: I think I know the reason why it throws exception in my original project. My project is Excel Add-In... Can it be loaded in Excel Add-In? The fact it throws exception there and loads fine in normal desktop project...

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1191#issuecomment-792311380

Comment: Alternatively you can run CefSharp out of process. There's a demo at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.OutOfProcess

Comment: If I do it out of process, I need somehow to deliver the data from one of the packets to my application...that's extra IPC...

Comment: BTW, my Excel Add-In is  COM Add-in, not Excel Add-In

Comment: Are you seeing the exception above in a WinForms application or a Excel COM Addin? Edit your question if required.

Comment: Getting exception in the Excel COM Add-In only. I did not have a choice but to switch to WebView2, which I like way less due to poor documentation, and more complex way to hook up the socket. However the exception File not found seems weird if whether has to do with AppDomain and managed/unmanaged code compatibility...

Comment: WebView2 runs the browser in a separate process (out of process) which is why it behaves differently. The Addin likely has a different working directory which is why it cannot resolve the dlls even when they appear to be next to your library. You'd use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve  to hook resolving them yourself if this is indeed the problem.